# Can I energize a circuit before it's inspected?

Tags: electrical, inspection, permitting

I live in Washington state, and state law requires electrical permits and inspections for locations without a municipal inspector to go through the state Labor and Industries (LNI) department. Homeowners are permitted to do their own electrical work, provided they apply for the appropriate permits and get their work inspected.

LNI's website states:

> You must request inspection:
>
> - Before you bury or conceal anything
> - Within 3 days of completing the installation or one day of energizing - whichever occurs first.

It's not explicitly stated, but the second item in this list seems to imply that circuits can be energized before inspection. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: I just built a house in Washington.  I had electricians doing the work, but everything was energized before inspection.

Comment: I'm not aware of anything that says you can't. IMO it *does* explicitly state "or [within] one day of energizing". How else would *you* check your work?

Comment: Are we talking rough or final? Rough wouldn’t be energized. Final will.

Comment: I think the spirit of the law is "you fixed it, great - Now shut it down and call us to check it".

Comment: "Within ... one day of energizing" seems clear and explicit enough. It will be on for up to 24 hours before testing...

Comment: I think the point of this is to allow you to energize things and begin testing and using them as long as the inspection is scheduled, without leaving a loophole that would allow you to do evade inspections by leaving things permanently in that "unfinished" state.

Comment: Since you're building anyway, install a generator interlock and an inlet on the side of the building.  You can flip to "generator" and power the house via the inlet, long before you get inspected and approved for utility power.   No, I don't mean an *actual* generator, I was more thinking off your EV's convenience outlet, neighbor, battery pack and the like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have quoted pretty clearly states that you "must request inspection within one day of energizing," which means they evidently don't expect it to be dead until inspected.

Particularly since I would guess that "requesting inspection" and "inspection happening" are generally separated by some time.